# What are the most common causes of death in the profession of computer programming?

Tags: cancer, posture, lifestyle, statistics, death

Some cancers such as colorectal cancer [are said](http://www.webmd.com/cancer/news/20140616/study-ties-too-much-sitting-to-risks-for-certain-cancers) to be associated with sitting too much.

I spent most of the day sitting down. While I could remind myself to stand up more regularly, I was wondering what other health risks programmers face and whether there are any studies dealing with the subject.

Comment: I very much doubt that anyone has studied causes of death in programmers specifically. You might want to edit your question to just ask about sedentary desk jobs.